# Obtener objeto que llama a función, dentro de la misma función

Tags: php, poo, funciones, object

Deseo obtener la instancia de una clase sin tener que pasarla como parámetro, ejemplo:

Carro.php

```
class Carro{

    protected $mensaje;

    static function prender($instancia) {
        $instancia->mensaje = "Carro prendido";
        return $instancia->mensaje;
    }
}
```

Fichero2.php

```
$instancia = new Carro();
echo "".$instancia::prender($instancia);
```

¿Es posible que en la función `prender()` se obtenga el objeto desde el cual se le está llamando, sin tener que pasarlo como parámetro? Preferiblemente, sin que deje de ser una función estática.

Comment: Pregunta... ¿No sería más fácil no declara el método como estático y hacer uso de `$this`?

Comment: No entiendo bien la cuestión... **¿quieres pasar una instancia de la clase a la misma clase?** ¿No te parece algo extraño? Quizá si comentas lo que pretendes hacer con la instancia de la clase dentro del método `prender` entonces podríamos dilucidar mejor el asunto y sugerirte talvez mejores formas de hacer lo que sea.

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer con la $instancia es poder asignarle un valor a la variable $mensaje, puesto que si lo hago con $this me genera error.

Answer (score -1):

si lo que necesitas es utilizar atributos de la clase dentro de la misma clase:

```
class Carro(){

    protected $mensaje;

    static function prender() {
        //$this hace referencia a la propia clase/instancia
        $this->mensaje = "Carro prendido";
        return $this->mensaje;
    }
 }
```

---

si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de una variable constante

```
class Carro()
{
    //variable accesible desde la clase sin tener que instanciar la clase
    const CONSTANTE = 'valor';
    const NUMERO = 1;
}
```

se utiliza:

```
echo Carro::CONSTANTE;
$suma = Carro::NUMERO +1;
```

---

si lo que necesitas hacer es usar un dato que no cambia con la ejecucion del código  usa `const`
si lo que necistas es poder operar con los atributos de la clase dentro de sus propias metodos, utiliza la pseudovariable `$this`

Comment: La variable de clase que tengo no es constante. Intenté utilizar la pseudovariable $this, sin embargo me arroja el error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: entonces publica tu codigo y no "ejemplos",  no podemos adivinar que esta mal en tu codigo